# Request login on edit mode profile form

Tags: wordpress, profile

I'm using CiviCRM 4.7.31 on WordPress with the Members plugin. I created a new profile, then embedded that form in edit mode within a WordPress page:

```
[civicrm component="profile" gid="35" mode="edit" hijack="0"]
```

As expected, the WordPress page generates an error if a user is not logged in:

> "No user/contact ID was specified, so the Profile cannot be used in
>   edit mode."

This error persists even when I set the page's Content Permissions to limit access to users in selected roles.

The error disappears when I wrap the civicrm shortcode within the members_logged_in shortcode:

```
[members_logged_in]
[civicrm component="profile" gid="35" mode="edit" hijack="0"]
[/members_logged_in]
```

But then the profile form loses its formatting; it seems like some Javascript/CSS is not loaded on the page when the shortcode is nested.

Is there a way to make this work correctly? Do I need to switch to Caldera Forms with the Caldera Forms CiviCRM plugin?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to make sure the Civi scripts loaded on the page. [This answer provides guidance](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16718/enable-use-of-do-shortcode-when-using-civicrm-and-wordpress-templates) on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find a solution? This is still happening with:
Wordpress version: 5.6
CiviCRM version: 5.32.2

I'm having a consulting team investigate, I'll report back if they find a solution.

UPDATE:
I found a VERY hacky workaround. I added this block to civicrm.shortcodes.php inside "prerender" function:

```
          // default regex FAILED. Support nested shortcodes with custom regex.
      if (empty($shortcodes_array)) {
        preg_match_all('/\[civicrm component="(contribution|event|profile|user-dashboard|petition)"( action="[a-z]+"| mode="[a-z]+")?( id="[0-9]")?( gid="[0-9]")?\]/', $post->post_content, $located);
        if (!empty($located) && !empty($located[0])) {
          $shortcodes_array = $located[0];
        }
      }
```

Here is the entire function with my custom block included:

```
  public function prerender( $wp ) {

/*
 * At this point, all conditional tags are available
 * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags
 */

// Bail if this is a 404
if ( is_404() ) return;

// A counter's useful
$shortcodes_present = 0;

/*
 * Let's loop through the results
 * This also has the effect of bypassing the logic in
 * https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-wordpress/pull/36
 */
if ( have_posts() ) {
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    global $post;

    // Check for existence of shortcode in content
    if ( has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'civicrm' ) ) {

      // Get CiviCRM shortcodes in this post
      $shortcodes_array = $this->get_for_post( $post->post_content );

      // default regex FAILED. Support nested shortcodes with custom regex.
      if (empty($shortcodes_array)) {
        preg_match_all('/\[civicrm component="(contribution|event|profile|user-dashboard|petition)"( action="[a-z]+"| mode="[a-z]+")?( id="[0-9]")?( gid="[0-9]")?\]/', $post->post_content, $located);
        if (!empty($located) && !empty($located[0])) {
          $shortcodes_array = $located[0];
        }
      }

      // Sanity check
      if ( !empty( $shortcodes_array ) ) {

        // Add it to our property
        $this->shortcodes[$post->ID] = $shortcodes_array;

        // Bump shortcode counter
        $shortcodes_present += count( $this->shortcodes[$post->ID] );

      }

    }

  endwhile;
}

// Reset loop
rewind_posts();

// Did we get any?
if ( $shortcodes_present ) {

  // We need CiviCRM initialised prior to parsing shortcodes
  if (!$this->civi->initialize()) {
    return;
  }

  // How should we handle multiple shortcodes?
  if ( $shortcodes_present > 1 ) {

    // Add CSS resources for front end
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this->civi, 'front_end_css_load' ), 100 );

    // Let's add dummy markup
    foreach( $this->shortcodes AS $post_id => $shortcode_array ) {

      // Set flag if there are multple shortcodes in this post
      $multiple = ( count( $shortcode_array ) > 1 ) ? 1 : 0;

      foreach( $shortcode_array AS $shortcode ) {

        // Mimic invoke in multiple shortcode context
        $this->shortcode_markup[$post_id][] = $this->render_multiple( $post_id, $shortcode, $multiple );

      }

    }

  } else {

    // Add core resources for front end
    add_action( 'wp', array( $this->civi, 'front_end_page_load' ), 100 );

    /*
     * Since we have only one shortcode, run the_loop again
     * the DB query has already been done, so this has no significant impact
     */
    if ( have_posts() ) {
      while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        global $post;

        // Is this the post?
        if ( ! array_key_exists( $post->ID, $this->shortcodes ) ) {
          continue;
        }

        // The shortcode must be the first item in the shortcodes array
        $shortcode = $this->shortcodes[$post->ID][0];

        // Check to see if a shortcode component has been repeated?
        $atts = $this->get_atts( $shortcode );

        // Test for hijacking
        if ( isset( $atts['hijack'] ) AND $atts['hijack'] == '1' ) {
          add_filter( 'civicrm_context', array( $this, 'get_context' ) );
        }

        // Store corresponding markup
        $this->shortcode_markup[$post->ID][] = do_shortcode( $shortcode );

        // Test for hijacking
        if ( isset( $atts['hijack'] ) AND $atts['hijack'] == '1' ) {

          // Ditch the filter
          remove_filter( 'civicrm_context', array( $this, 'get_context' ) );

          // Set title
          global $civicrm_wp_title;
          $post->post_title = $civicrm_wp_title;

          // Override page title
          add_filter( 'single_post_title', array( $this->civi, 'single_page_title' ), 50, 2 );

          // Overwrite content
          add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'get_content' ) );

        }

      endwhile;
    }

    // Reset loop
    rewind_posts();

  }

}

// Flag that we have parsed shortcodes
$this->shortcodes_parsed = TRUE;

/**
 * Broadcast that shortcodes have been parsed.
 *
 * @since 4.6
 */
do_action( 'civicrm_shortcodes_parsed' );
```

}

Please reply if there's a better way to do this!