# Parsing search shortcodes by Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress

When trying to fix this issue [Search ajax script "not a valid JavaScript MIME type"](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33700/search-ajax-script-not-a-valid-javascript-mime-type) by attempting to bypass added editor plugins, I'm using the WordPress plugin Advanced Custom Fields to add another WYSIWYG editor.

I'm using the standard `get_field` call with `do_shortcode` in the page template file:

```
<?php
if( get_field('civicrm_shortcode') ) {
echo do_shortcode(get_field('civicrm_shortcode')); }
?>
```

I can use a simple shortcode with no parameters in the WYSIWYG editor, i.e. `[a_simple_shortcode]` and it works; but using the CiviCRM shortcode with parameters, i.e. `[civicrm component="profile" gid="14" mode="create" hijack="0"]` shows nothing.

Is this a ACF or CiviCRM issue? Is it possible to get ACF or CiviCRM to parse the CiviCRM shortcode?

Comment: Works for me - the shortcode renders just fine. I have a field of type "text" attached to a field group which shows on WordPress pages. I added your code to a custom template for a page. With the demo data loaded into CiviCRM, I then added `[civicrm component="profile" gid="1" mode="create" hijack="0"]` to the field. The "Name and Address" profile rendered perfectly.

Comment: What I'm saying is... I think we need more info about your setup...

Comment: Ah, hold on... it renders fine, but the CiviCRM resources are not added to the page header... See this answer for the solution to that https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/16723/520

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but now with CiviCRM loading, I get the same console errors as https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33700/search-ajax-script-not-a-valid-javascript-mime-type

Comment: Something must be a conflict in your setup. As I said, on a vanilla install (just CiviCRM and ACF) everything works as expected.

Comment: Manually loading the script with `<script>` tags on the one page still throws the MIME error.