# do_shortcode() not render CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress

I'm using `do_shortcode()` to render a specific CiviCRM propfile on a specific section of my site.

`do_shortcode('[civicrm component="profile" gid="34" mode="create" hijack="1"]')`

Also tried: `apply_filters('the_content', $shortcode)`

But the form is not rendered. I tested the same form on a page editor and it's rendered. The do_shortcode only works if the page has another CiviCRM shortcode inside the content editor.

Comment: Is this same issue? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16718/enable-use-of-do-shortcode-when-using-civicrm-and-wordpress-templates